# Как записать селектор правильнее?

Tags: css, css3, sass

Есть селектор:

```
.сontainer > .root_bcf436ba > .ms-Viewport > .root_3a38b365 {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Где мой класс это-`.сontainer`, далее в него вкладываются div'ы с классами библиотеки. В этом классе `.root_3a38b365` меняется размер шрифта.
Переназначить свойство класса библиотеки не вариант. Можно ли еще как-то подобраться к классу `.root_3a38b365` через более короткий селектор? И как лучше это прописать в SASS?

Comment: `.root_3a38b365` - это `div`? Замените его банально на див. А можно ещё проще: `.container .root_3a38b365`

Comment: Если этот класс уникален(иначе для чего он генерируется?) используйте только его: `.root_3a38b365 {}`

Comment: Судя по коду, код генерируется "на лету" (как в Инстаграмме), поэтому Ваши селекторы в следующий раз могут не совпасть, старайтесь пользоваться только тегами. И лучше приведите хотя бы относительно полный код

Comment: .container .ms-Viewport [class^='root_']
или уверены в уникальности ".ms-Viewport"


.ms-Viewport [class^='root_']